# Select com Join alternativo MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Table - log_tables_restaurants

```
id    |  id_restaurant  | id_admin   |  id_user  | action 
 1    | 10              |   2        |  NULL     | adicionou 2 mesas
 2    | 11              |   3        |  NULL     | removeu 2 mesas
 3    | 20              |   NULL     |  30       | adicionou 10 mesas
```

Tenho que fazer um select que liste os dados dessa tabela porém essa tabela pode se relacionar ou com a tabela de administrator ou com a tabela de users para saber quem fez o registro.

```
SELECT log_tables_restaurants.id
      ,log_tables_restaurants.id_restaurant
      ,**administrator.name OU users.first_name**
      ,log_tables_restaurants.day_week
      ,log_tables_restaurants.action
      ,log_tables_restaurants.created_at 
  FROM log_tables_restaurants, restaurants, administrator 
 WHERE ((id_region = '1')) 
   AND log_tables_restaurants.id_restaurant = restaurants.id 
   AND log_tables_restaurants.id_admin = administrator.id **OU logs_tables_restaurants.id_user = users.id**
```

Minha dúvida está onde marquei com negrito, ja que na listagem quero saber o nome de quem fez a inclusão de um registro na tabela, como ficaria essa query ?

Comment: O ideal seria realmente refazer do zero com um `JOIN` de verdade, mas pra aproveitar essa aí seria algo assim: `... AND (log_tables_restaurants.id_admin =  administrator.id OR logs_tables_restaurants.id_user = users.id)` - O que me causa estranheza é ter tabelas separadas para admin e user, mas aí foge do perguntado.

Comment: Como ficar essa parte  (administrator.name OU users.first_name) usando a lógica que você mencionou ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na parte do `SELECT`, para obter o nome:

```
COALESCE(administrator.name, users.first_name) AS nome
```

Ou, pode usar um IF:

```
IF(log_tables_restaurants.id_admin IS NULL, users.first_name, administrator.name) AS nome
```

E na parte do `WHERE`, usam-se parênteses e o `OR` para a alternativa:

```
... AND (
       log_tables_restaurants.id_admin = administrator.id
       OR
       logs_tables_restaurants.id_user = users.id
    )
```